# Insert the element diagonally in c program

Tags: c, matrix

What is the procedure to insert the element diagonally?

A function will take matrix.

Examples

1. `a[1,2,3]`;

This will give the following output

```
1 0 0 
0 2 0
0 0 3
```

2. Similarly, `b[1,2,3,4,5,6]` should give:

```or-tag-here
1 0 0 0 0 0
0 2 0 0 0 0
0 0 3 0 0 0
0 0 0 4 0 0
0 0 0 0 5 0
0 0 0 0 0 6
```

Comment: its not initializing it is passing array

Comment: The second table was not correct, edited

Comment: Insert? You mean, just set or replace? In most programming contexts, "inserting" implies moving existing elements to make room for new elements. Here it looks like you want to just change values of existing items? Or create and return an new matrix?

Comment: Do you want to pass a variable size array as pointer or a fixed size?

Comment: Anyway, what is your problem, what error or wrong output do you get with your current code? What input you give, and what output you expect?

Comment: Insert the elements at diagonally and rest of the elements remains 0 and should be square matrix

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int A[]={1,2,3,5,6,7},i,j;
    for(i=0;i<sizeof(A)/sizeof(int);i++) {
    for(j=0;j<sizeof(A)/sizeof(int);j++)
    if(i==j)
        printf("%d ",A[i]);
    else
        printf("0 ");
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-‌​code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: :) I'll try the best next.

Comment: I have solved issue by myself